# Add SSL to a domain serving kubernetes app

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, amazon-elb, kops

I am using kops to deploy my kubernetes cluster. in my cluster, I have a simple Nginx deployment, a service, and an ingress. Its configured with route 53 (not using external DNS, manually creating A record in route 53 pointing to a classic load balancer (generated by kops)).

I can hit the domain [www.XXXX.com](http://www.XXXX.com) as well as a subdomain on it but, there is not SSL certificate on it.

I know we can apply SSL on the loadbalancer. So, went in ACM, created a certificate and when I try to apply it, I see 80 and 443 are serving TCP traffic, that's why I cannot add these two ports serving HTTP and HTTPS with certificate (as shown in image)
[image]

If I delete the two TCP listeners and add HTTP and HTTPS listners I can, but then my app is not reachable on the domain.

How can I configure ACM on this loadbalancer. Is this even a correct way of adding https for an app deployed on Kubernetes?

I know about https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/, but if there is a way to do it using above approach I would prefer that.

---

UPDATE 1:

when I describe my nginx pod I see Ports as follows:

```
Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP
```

shouldn't that be

```
Ports:         80/HTTP, 443/HTTPS
```

?

Comment: Removing the 2 TCP listeners should allow this. What do you mean by domain is not reachable? Also any reason for using a classic load balancer and not using an application load balancer? :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams updated why I think removing TCP will not work. the classic load balancer was default with kops. no other reason. if this is any easier with application load balancer   I am down for it.

Comment: Its more down to the facts that the classic load balancer is generally legacy. HTTP/HTTPS are TCP protocols that operate at layer 7. I'd suggest making a secondary load balancer that is the ALB and test against that. Regarding your pods, port 80 and port 443 are the layer 4 configurations defaultly used for HTTP and HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I deployed the ingress controller incorrectly.

the documentation clearly says  **download and update values in the file** before applying I missed the updating part.

You have to update CIDR `proxy-real-ip-cidr` and `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert`

literally that all you need.

make sure you are creating a certificate before applying this YAML file.

and while creating cert add

DOMAIN.com
*.DOMAIN.com

both to make it work.